# Implements inner Fragment class in parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have the following code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment.SendToActivity {
  ...
  public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    
    SendToActivity callback;

    public void setSendToActivity (SendToActivity callback) {
      this.callback = callback;
    }

    public interface SendToActivity {
      public void send(int result);
    }
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment instanceof SettingsFragment) {
      SettingsFragment settingsFragment = (SettingsFragment) fragment;
      settingsFragment.setSendToActivity(this);
    }
  }

  public void send(int result) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But I get the following error: `cyclic inheritance involving SettingsActivity` in the the declaration of the SettingsActivity class. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `SendToActivity` defined?

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh editing...

Comment: @CommonsWare Edited.

Comment: Try moving that to be just inside `SettingsActivity`, without it being inside your `inner class`. That would change the `implements` to be `SettingsActivity.SendToActivity`.

Comment: If I just use `SettingsFragment.SendToActivity` after `implements` word, `SettingsFragment` gets red and says: `cannot find symbol`.

Comment: @CommonsWare move what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself: The fragment class needs to be on its own java file. Then just implement it normally (`implements SettingsFragment.SendToActivity`).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `SendToActivity` out of `SettingsFragment`, such as:

```java
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SettingsActivity.SendToActivity {
  public interface SendToActivity {
    public void send(int result);
  }

  ...

  public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    
    SendToActivity callback;

    public void setSendToActivity (SendToActivity callback) {
      this.callback = callback;
    }

    ...

  }

  @Override
  public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment instanceof SettingsFragment) {
      SettingsFragment settingsFragment = (SettingsFragment) fragment;
      settingsFragment.setSendToActivity(this);
    }
  }

  public void send(int result) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: @Mike087: Hmmm... try `public static interface SendToActivity`.

Comment: Tried. I got the same error.

Comment: @Mike087: OK, then, it probably needs to be a top-level `interface`, not nested inside of a class that looks to implement that interface.